# Traversing/Manipulating new window from parent window with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, browser, window

I found a question already with a possible solution, but I had already tried the method suggested before reading it, and it even says it's inconsistent. So I guess I'm wondering why this doesn't work:

```
$("img").click(function() {
    var imgwindow = window.open('imgwin.html','','width=460,height=345');
    alert(imgwindow.find("img").attr("src"));
});
```

The goal is to set the new window's `img` to the same `src` as the image that the user clicked to open the new window. But in the above scenario, I'm just trying to tap into the new window to get what it's already-set src. I have `imgwin.html` already written with a default `src` for the image, so it should alert that url. Instead I just get `undefined`.

I also tried the following (which should be identical on the back end), but with the same results:

```
$("img").click(function() {
    var imgwindow = window.open('imgwin.html','','width=460,height=345');
    alert($("img",imgwindow).attr("src"));
});
```

I even tried variations of wrapping the `imgwindow` variable in `$()` in case somehow jquery wasn't picking up on the variable as a DOM element.

The only thing I can guess is that since `window.open()` is a method, jquery doesn't treat it like a DOM element, even though all documentation from basic javascript tutorials treat the variable as both a method to open the window and the pointer to the window's inner DOM.

### Note:

I usually prefer and recommend to other developers the use of the jquery-ui dialog widget, but in this scenario, the images are actually webcam feeds that the user will want to pop out of the main window and have open even if the main window is closed, so while I appreciate the move from popup windows in general, please avoid suggesting alternatives that involve same-window widgets. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty

```
var src = '';
var imgwindow;
$(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
    imgwindow = window.open('urlto.html','','width=460,height=345');
    src = this.src;
    //delay needed as I couldn't manage to get ready/load events to work on the
    //imgwindow.document object
    //thus the snippet is dirtier then need with all those "global" variables
    setTimeout('$("img", imgwindow.document.body).attr("src", src)', 1000);
  });
});
```

**Note:** Only tested in Opera. `imgwindow.document` might not work for all browsers. At least I recall there being problems for iframes where document/contentDocument and maybe others "identifiers" are needed to get the "document" of the new window/iframe. But just test in any browsers you need to support

Comment: I'm still trying to digest your answer, but I think your issue with the delay might actually be the real answer to my confusion. The reason I was getting undefined was because the new window hasn't loaded yet when the alert happens. Well of course! I'll test this theory and post a final update if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

why not just do this

```
$("img").click(function(e) {
var src = $(this).attr('src');
window.open(src,'','width=460,height=345');
});
```

This will open a new window with your image inside! ;-)

#### UPDATE

In response to your comment, need to do something like this:

```
$("img").click(function(e) {
//Load content in your page and hide it...
$('#result').load('imgwin.html').hide();
//find the image you want...
 alert($('#result').find("img").attr("src"));
//remove it from your page..
$('#result').remove();
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

ok, still on this, i like it! ;-)

try this:

```
var reg = /src=\"(.+[\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif])\"/;  
var imgwindow = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "imgwin.html", async: false  }).responseText;
var img = imgwindow.match(reg)[1];
alert(img);
```

Comment: I considered that, but I need other HTML to be embedded into the new window, so that if the parent window closes, the new window has its own controls. I'm mostly confused why I can't find any solutions on how to do this. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: This is a sneaky work around. I must admit it's clever. But I avoid hiding when possible and I think jitter may have touched on the real source of my confusion. +1 for creativity.